# how to show success message when password match in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 fields password and confirm password I want to show the message in span or `ng-message` password match or any string showing the password matched before submit button is clicked.

I am thinking of using this but don't know how to show message in this for password match success.

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FipgiTUaaymm5Mk6HIfn?p=preview)

these are the ng message used in this code`

```
<div class="messages">
    <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Too long</div>
    <div ng-message="email">Invalid email address</div>
   <div ng-message="compareTo">Must match the previous entry</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zqVskmlBEgdk5f1hIh05?p=preview this may helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $valid attribute. Something like the below HTML

```
<div class="messages">
    <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Too long</div>
    <div ng-message="email">Invalid email address</div>
    <div ng-message="compareTo">Must match the previous entry</div>
    <div ng-if="[yourForm].$valid">Password is valid</div>
</div>
```